# remove duplicates and collapse near duplicates based on time difference

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have a data-frame like as shown below

```
DF = structure(list(Age_visit = c(48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 77), Date_1 = c("8/6/2169 9:40", "8/6/2169 9:40", 
                                                                     "8/6/2169 9:41", "8/6/2169 9:42", "24/7/2169 8:31", "12/9/2169 10:30", 
                                                                     "19/6/2237 12:15"), Date_2 = c("NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA", "NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA", "NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA", 
                                                                                                            "NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA", "NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA", "NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA", 
                                                                                                            "NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA"), person_id = c("21",
                                                                                                                                                  "21", 
                                                                                                                                                  "21", 
                                                                                                                                                  "21", 
                                                                                                                                                  "21", 
                                                                                                                                                  "21", 
                                                                                                                                                  "31"
                                                                                                            ), enc_id = c("A21BC","A21BC", 
                                                                                                                                       "A22BC", 
                                                                                                                                       "A23BC", 
                                                                                                                                       "A24BC", 
                                                                                                                                       "A25BC", 
                                                                                                                                       "A31BC"
                                                                                                            )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                            ))
```

**dataframe**

```
  Age_visit Date_1          Date_2            person_id enc_id
      <dbl> <chr>           <chr>             <chr>     <chr> 
1        48 8/6/2169 9:40   NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA  21        A21BC 
2        48 8/6/2169 9:40   NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA  21        A21BC 
3        48 8/6/2169 9:41   NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA  21        A22BC 
4        49 8/6/2169 9:42   NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA  21        A23BC 
5        49 24/7/2169 8:31  NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA  21        A24BC 
6        77 12/9/2169 10:30 NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA  31        A31BC
```

I have two rules/steps to be implemented.

**Rule-1 (step-1)**

First, remove duplicates based on 3 columns like `Date_1`, `person_id`, `enc_id`

```
DF[!duplicated(DF[,c('Date_1','person_id','enc_id')]),]  # this will remove 1st row as it's a plain straight forward duplicate
```

**Rule-2 (step-2)**

From the output of step-1, collapse near duplicate records (notice tiny differences in `DATE_1` and `enc_id` columns) based on time into one single record if the time difference between these records is less than hour.

For ex, if you see `person_id = 21`, you can see that after step-1, all his `Date_1` time values are on the same day but the difference is only one minute (9:40 --> 9:41 --> 9:42). Since it's less than an hour (60 mins), we collapse all of them into one single record and retain only the first record (which is for 9:40). **We do this check for each subject in the dataframe**

I have removed the duplicates based on few columns like as shown below

```
DF[!duplicated(DF[,c('Date_1','person_id','enc_id')]),]
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
  Age_visit Date_1          Date_2            person_id enc_id
      <dbl> <chr>           <chr>             <chr>     <chr> 
1        48 8/6/2169 9:40   NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA  21        A21BC 
4        49 24/7/2169 8:31  NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA  21        A24BC 
5        77 12/9/2169 10:30 NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA  31        A31BC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rolling join option using `data.table`:

```
DT[, c("rn", "hrago") := .(.I, Date_1 - 60 * 60)]
DT[DT[DT, on=.(person_id, Date_1=hrago), roll=-Inf, unique(rn)]]
```

output:

```
   Age_visit              Date_1 person_id enc_id rn               hrago
1:        48 2169-06-08 09:40:00        21  A21BC  1 2169-06-08 08:40:00
2:        49 2169-07-24 08:31:00        21  A24BC  5 2169-07-24 07:31:00
3:        77 2169-09-12 10:30:00        31  A31BC  6 2169-09-12 09:30:00
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Age_visit Date_1    person_id enc_id
48 8/6/2169-9:40    21        A21BC 
48 8/6/2169-9:40    21        A21BC 
48 8/6/2169-9:41    21        A22BC 
49 8/6/2169-9:42    21        A23BC 
49 24/7/2169-8:31   21        A24BC 
77 12/9/2169-10:30  31        A31BC") 
DT[, Date_1 := as.POSIXct(Date_1, format="%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M")]
```

---

Explanation:

1) `DT[DT, on=.(person_id, Date_1=hrago),` is a self-join using `person_id` from both tables and `Date_1` from right table and `hrago` from left table.

2) `roll=-Inf` rolls the observation in the right table backwards if an identical match for the observation in the left table is not found

3) `unique(rn)` takes the unique rows from the right table and then filter the table for these rows.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. Will try your answer as well and update the answer if required

Comment: Hi, Sorry new to R. My input data is in data frame format. So, I have to convert my dataframe to data table to use this solution?

Comment: Thanks. I was reding about data table and rolling join, but can you help me understand what does this line of code do?  `DT[DT[DT, on=.(person_id, Date_1=hrago), roll=-Inf, unique(rn)]]`

Comment: I know it's rolling backward and joining based on two keys which are person_id and hrago. Joining DT datatable to itself???

Comment: @TheGreat i added some explanation in the post

Comment: Hi @chinsoon12 - Is there a way to view the operations occuring within the above line of code? When I split that line into 2-3 parts, it doesn't show me the self-joined tables. Meaning when I do `DT[DT, on=.(person_id, Date_1=hrago), roll=-Inf, unique(rn)]`, it gives only the index number. When I just write, `[DT, on=.(person_id, Date_1=hrago), roll=-Inf, unique(rn)]`, it throws synatx error. How can I view the self-joined tables or how do they do the rolling jpin. If I write `DT[DT[DT, on=.(person_id, Date_1=hrago), roll=-Inf, unique(rn)]]`, I get the output but unable to see internal work

Comment: can help please?

Comment: Maybe u can start with the vignette? You can try DT[DT, on=.(person_id, Date_1=hrago)]. Then add roll argument. And you are trying to understand how the rolling join is performed and the internal workings you will need to read the source codes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212063/discussion-between-the-great-and-chinsoon12).

Answer (score 2):

Your question can be solved using a dplyr pipeline.

- The first step solves the duplicate problem using `distinct()`.
- The seconds step changes the Date_1 column into a Datetime type (necessary for calculating time difference.
- The third step adds a column with the previous timestamp using `lag()`. This must be in a `group_by()` on person_id to make sure that time stamps are not shifted to other people. Also, it is important to make sure the date is arrange properly (using the `arrange()`).
- The fourth step calculates a time difference since the previous timestamp in seconds. This will give an NA for the first row of a person.
- The fifth step removes all records with a time difference of less than one hour
- The last step removes all additional columns that were created in the pipeline.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  distinct(Date_1, person_id , enc_id, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  mutate(Date_1 = as.POSIXct(Date_1, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')) %>% 
  group_by(person_id) %>% 
  arrange(Date_1) %>%
  mutate(Date_lag = lag(Date_1)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Date_diff = difftime(Date_1, Date_lag, units = 'secs')) %>% 
  filter(is.na(Date_diff) | Date_diff >= 3600) %>% 
  select(Age_visit, Date_1, Date_2, person_id, enc_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do both in the same step, by checking successive time difference. Duplicates have a time difference of 0:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

DF %>%
  group_by(person_id)%>%
  mutate(Date_1 = dmy_hm(Date_1)) %>%
  arrange((Date_1)) %>%
  filter(c(5000,diff(Date_1))>3600)


  Age_visit Date_1              Date_2            person_id enc_id
      <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>             <chr>     <chr> 
1        48 2169-06-08 09:40:00 NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA 21        A21BC 
2        49 2169-07-24 08:31:00 NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA 21        A24BC 
3        77 2169-09-12 10:30:00 NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA 31        A25BC
```

There was a mistake in your data (person_id 31 was missing). Here is the one I used:

```
DF = structure(list(Age_visit = c(48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 77), Date_1 = c("8/6/2169 9:40", "8/6/2169 9:40", 
                                                                      "8/6/2169 9:41", "8/6/2169 9:42", "24/7/2169 8:31", "12/9/2169 10:30", 
                                                                      "19/6/2237 12:15"), Date_2 = c("NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA", "NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA", "NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA", 
                                                                                                     "NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA", "NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA", "NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA", 
                                                                                                     "NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA"), person_id = c("21",
                                                                                                                                         "21", 
                                                                                                                                         "21", 
                                                                                                                                         "21", 
                                                                                                                                         "21", 
                                                                                                                                         "31"
                                                                                                     ), enc_id = c("A21BC","A21BC", 
                                                                                                                   "A22BC", 
                                                                                                                   "A23BC", 
                                                                                                                   "A24BC", 
                                                                                                                   "A25BC", 
                                                                                                                   "A31BC"
                                                                                                     )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                     ))
```

Comment: Yes, good point. The rolling join option is far better and cleaner. Thanks !